# Filtering JSON object in vue to compute new one

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

I have a JSON object that looks like this that comes from my server,

```
    [
   {
      "id":1,
      "tag":"Cooking",
      "weight":null,
      "deleted_at":null,
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "listings":[
         {
            "id":5,
            "name":"Learn how to make the perfect hotpot with",
            "slug":"learn-how-to-make-the-perfect-hotpot-with",
            "description":"We live in a unique and wonderful time where electric guitars are things that we can rock on. \n\nIn this lesson, I want to be blown away by what you do. And I can reveal my story. And how I went from a woman who had no idea what she was doing to making sounds and songs that felt that they were very honest to me and pushed boundaries that I didn’t even know existed. And I want to try to be a wind in your sails and a steel in your spine as you’re trying to go from being a good guitar player to not just being a great guitar player, but being someone who really finds themselves in their instrument.\n\nI’d like to teach a class that makes your guitar playing meaningful to you. Whatever it is that you want to do in it. If you want to play exactly like me, well, you’re going to figure that out in this lesson. If you want to play guitar playing that feels exactly like you, hopefully, we will - I’ll reveal the building blocks of how you can do that to create an authentic, artistic self on the electric guitar that’s going to be something that is going to give you a lifetime of awesome rockin’.",
            "booking_details":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
            "cost":"25.00",
            "active":1,
            "moderated":1,
            "user_id":3,
            "category_id":null,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:41:05.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2020-06-24T22:50:48.000000Z",
            "tagsList":"Cooking",
            "pivot":{
               "tag_id":1,
               "listing_id":5
            },
            "primary_image":[
               {
                  "id":5,
                  "type":"image",
                  "url":"https://xxxxxxx.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/learn-how-to-make-the-perfect-hotpot-with/primary-image-lg.jpg",
                  "is_primary":1,
                  "assetable_type":"App\\Listing",
                  "assetable_id":5,
                  "desktop":1,
                  "mobile":null,
                  "user_id":3,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:41:07.000000Z",
                  "updated_at":"2020-06-18T13:41:07.000000Z"
               },
               {
                  "id":6,
                  "type":"image",
                  "url":"https://xxxxxxx.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/learn-how-to-make-the-perfect-hotpot-with/primary-image-sm.jpg",
                  "is_primary":1,
                  "assetable_type":"App\\Listing",
                  "assetable_id":5,
                  "desktop":null,
                  "mobile":1,
                  "user_id":3,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:41:07.000000Z",
                  "updated_at":"2020-06-18T13:41:07.000000Z"
               }
            ],
            "tags":[
               {
                  "id":1,
                  "tag":"Cooking",
                  "weight":null,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":null,
                  "updated_at":null,
                  "pivot":{
                     "listing_id":5,
                     "tag_id":1
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "tag":"Fitness",
      "weight":null,
      "deleted_at":null,
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "listings":[
         {
            "id":6,
            "name":"Bodyweight fitness workouts made",
            "slug":"bodyweight-fitness-workouts-made",
            "description":"We live in a unique and wonderful time where electric guitars are things that we can rock on. \n\nIn this lesson, I want to be blown away by what you do. And I can reveal my story. And how I went from a woman who had no idea what she was doing to making sounds and songs that felt that they were very honest to me and pushed boundaries that I didn’t even know existed. And I want to try to be a wind in your sails and a steel in your spine as you’re trying to go from being a good guitar player to not just being a great guitar player, but being someone who really finds themselves in their instrument.\n\nI’d like to teach a class that makes your guitar playing meaningful to you. Whatever it is that you want to do in it. If you want to play exactly like me, well, you’re going to figure that out in this lesson. If you want to play guitar playing that feels exactly like you, hopefully, we will - I’ll reveal the building blocks of how you can do that to create an authentic, artistic self on the electric guitar that’s going to be something that is going to give you a lifetime of awesome rockin’.",
            "booking_details":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
            "cost":"10.00",
            "active":1,
            "moderated":1,
            "user_id":3,
            "category_id":null,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:41:49.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2020-06-18T13:41:49.000000Z",
            "tagsList":"Fitness",
            "pivot":{
               "tag_id":2,
               "listing_id":6
            },
            "primary_image":[
               {
                  "id":7,
                  "type":"image",
                  "url":"https://xxxxxxx.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bodyweight-fitness-workouts-made/primary-image-lg.jpg",
                  "is_primary":1,
                  "assetable_type":"App\\Listing",
                  "assetable_id":6,
                  "desktop":1,
                  "mobile":null,
                  "user_id":3,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:41:50.000000Z",
                  "updated_at":"2020-06-18T13:41:50.000000Z"
               },
               {
                  "id":8,
                  "type":"image",
                  "url":"https://xxxxxxx.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bodyweight-fitness-workouts-made/primary-image-sm.jpg",
                  "is_primary":1,
                  "assetable_type":"App\\Listing",
                  "assetable_id":6,
                  "desktop":null,
                  "mobile":1,
                  "user_id":3,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:41:50.000000Z",
                  "updated_at":"2020-06-18T13:41:50.000000Z"
               }
            ],
            "tags":[
               {
                  "id":2,
                  "tag":"Fitness",
                  "weight":null,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":null,
                  "updated_at":null,
                  "pivot":{
                     "listing_id":6,
                     "tag_id":2
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":7,
            "name":"Learn how to use TRX bands with",
            "slug":"learn-how-to-use-trx-bands-with",
            "description":"We live in a unique and wonderful time where electric guitars are things that we can rock on. \n\nIn this lesson, I want to be blown away by what you do. And I can reveal my story. And how I went from a woman who had no idea what she was doing to making sounds and songs that felt that they were very honest to me and pushed boundaries that I didn’t even know existed. And I want to try to be a wind in your sails and a steel in your spine as you’re trying to go from being a good guitar player to not just being a great guitar player, but being someone who really finds themselves in their instrument.\n\nI’d like to teach a class that makes your guitar playing meaningful to you. Whatever it is that you want to do in it. If you want to play exactly like me, well, you’re going to figure that out in this lesson. If you want to play guitar playing that feels exactly like you, hopefully, we will - I’ll reveal the building blocks of how you can do that to create an authentic, artistic self on the electric guitar that’s going to be something that is going to give you a lifetime of awesome rockin’.",
            "booking_details":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
            "cost":"10.00",
            "active":1,
            "moderated":1,
            "user_id":3,
            "category_id":null,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:42:15.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2020-06-18T13:42:15.000000Z",
            "tagsList":"Fitness",
            "pivot":{
               "tag_id":2,
               "listing_id":7
            },
            "primary_image":[
               {
                  "id":9,
                  "type":"image",
                  "url":"https://xxxxxxx.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/learn-how-to-use-trx-bands-with/primary-image-lg.jpg",
                  "is_primary":1,
                  "assetable_type":"App\\Listing",
                  "assetable_id":7,
                  "desktop":1,
                  "mobile":null,
                  "user_id":3,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:42:16.000000Z",
                  "updated_at":"2020-06-18T13:42:16.000000Z"
               },
               {
                  "id":10,
                  "type":"image",
                  "url":"https://xxxxxxx.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/learn-how-to-use-trx-bands-with/primary-image-sm.jpg",
                  "is_primary":1,
                  "assetable_type":"App\\Listing",
                  "assetable_id":7,
                  "desktop":null,
                  "mobile":1,
                  "user_id":3,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:42:16.000000Z",
                  "updated_at":"2020-06-18T13:42:16.000000Z"
               }
            ],
            "tags":[
               {
                  "id":2,
                  "tag":"Fitness",
                  "weight":null,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":null,
                  "updated_at":null,
                  "pivot":{
                     "listing_id":7,
                     "tag_id":2
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "tag":"Music",
      "weight":null,
      "deleted_at":null,
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "listings":[
         {
            "id":3,
            "name":"Learn the basics of the guitar  from the anatomy of the  guitar to scales, chords",
            "slug":"learn-the-basics-of-the-guitar-from-the-anatomy-of-the-guitar-to-scales-chords",
            "description":"We live in a unique and wonderful time where electric guitars are things that we can rock on. \n\nIn this lesson, I want to be blown away by what you do. And I can reveal my story. And how I went from a woman who had no idea what she was doing to making sounds and songs that felt that they were very honest to me and pushed boundaries that I didn’t even know existed. And I want to try to be a wind in your sails and a steel in your spine as you’re trying to go from being a good guitar player to not just being a great guitar player, but being someone who really finds themselves in their instrument.\n\nI’d like to teach a class that makes your guitar playing meaningful to you. Whatever it is that you want to do in it. If you want to play exactly like me, well, you’re going to figure that out in this lesson. If you want to play guitar playing that feels exactly like you, hopefully, we will - I’ll reveal the building blocks of how you can do that to create an authentic, artistic self on the electric guitar that’s going to be something that is going to give you a lifetime of awesome rockin’.",
            "booking_details":"undefined",
            "cost":"25.00",
            "active":1,
            "moderated":1,
            "user_id":3,
            "category_id":null,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:27:35.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2020-06-24T10:41:46.000000Z",
            "tagsList":"Music",
            "pivot":{
               "tag_id":3,
               "listing_id":3
            },
            "primary_image":[
               {
                  "id":1,
                  "type":"image",
                  "url":"https://xxxxxxx.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/learn-the-basics-of-the-guitar-from-the-anatomy-of-the-guitar-to-scales-chords/primary-image-lg.jpg",
                  "is_primary":1,
                  "assetable_type":"App\\Listing",
                  "assetable_id":3,
                  "desktop":1,
                  "mobile":null,
                  "user_id":3,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:27:36.000000Z",
                  "updated_at":"2020-06-18T13:27:36.000000Z"
               },
               {
                  "id":2,
                  "type":"image",
                  "url":"https://at-home-club-1.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/learn-the-basics-of-the-guitar-from-the-anatomy-of-the-guitar-to-scales-chords/primary-image-sm.jpg",
                  "is_primary":1,
                  "assetable_type":"App\\Listing",
                  "assetable_id":3,
                  "desktop":null,
                  "mobile":1,
                  "user_id":3,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:27:37.000000Z",
                  "updated_at":"2020-06-18T13:27:37.000000Z"
               }
            ],
            "tags":[
               {
                  "id":3,
                  "tag":"Music",
                  "weight":null,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":null,
                  "updated_at":null,
                  "pivot":{
                     "listing_id":3,
                     "tag_id":3
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":8,
            "name":"Advanced guitar skills with William Topa",
            "slug":"advanced-guitar-skills-with-william-topa",
            "description":"We live in a unique and wonderful time where electric guitars are things that we can rock on. \n\nIn this lesson, I want to be blown away by what you do. And I can reveal my story. And how I went from a woman who had no idea what she was doing to making sounds and songs that felt that they were very honest to me and pushed boundaries that I didn’t even know existed. And I want to try to be a wind in your sails and a steel in your spine as you’re trying to go from being a good guitar player to not just being a great guitar player, but being someone who really finds themselves in their instrument.\n\nI’d like to teach a class that makes your guitar playing meaningful to you. Whatever it is that you want to do in it. If you want to play exactly like me, well, you’re going to figure that out in this lesson. If you want to play guitar playing that feels exactly like you, hopefully, we will - I’ll reveal the building blocks of how you can do that to create an authentic, artistic self on the electric guitar that’s going to be something that is going to give you a lifetime of awesome rockin’.",
            "booking_details":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
            "cost":"0.00",
            "active":1,
            "moderated":1,
            "user_id":3,
            "category_id":null,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:42:44.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2020-06-18T13:42:44.000000Z",
            "tagsList":"Music",
            "pivot":{
               "tag_id":3,
               "listing_id":8
            },
            "primary_image":[
               {
                  "id":11,
                  "type":"image",
                  "url":"https://xxxxxxx.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/advanced-guitar-skills-with-william-topa/primary-image-lg.jpg",
                  "is_primary":1,
                  "assetable_type":"App\\Listing",
                  "assetable_id":8,
                  "desktop":1,
                  "mobile":null,
                  "user_id":3,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:42:45.000000Z",
                  "updated_at":"2020-06-18T13:42:45.000000Z"
               },
               {
                  "id":12,
                  "type":"image",
                  "url":"https://at-home-club-1.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/advanced-guitar-skills-with-william-topa/primary-image-sm.jpg",
                  "is_primary":1,
                  "assetable_type":"App\\Listing",
                  "assetable_id":8,
                  "desktop":null,
                  "mobile":1,
                  "user_id":3,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:42:46.000000Z",
                  "updated_at":"2020-06-18T13:42:46.000000Z"
               }
            ],
            "tags":[
               {
                  "id":3,
                  "tag":"Music",
                  "weight":null,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":null,
                  "updated_at":null,
                  "pivot":{
                     "listing_id":8,
                     "tag_id":3
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":9,
            "name":"Music production simplified",
            "slug":"music-production-simplified",
            "description":"We live in a unique and wonderful time where electric guitars are things that we can rock on. \n\nIn this lesson, I want to be blown away by what you do. And I can reveal my story. And how I went from a woman who had no idea what she was doing to making sounds and songs that felt that they were very honest to me and pushed boundaries that I didn’t even know existed. And I want to try to be a wind in your sails and a steel in your spine as you’re trying to go from being a good guitar player to not just being a great guitar player, but being someone who really finds themselves in their instrument.\n\nI’d like to teach a class that makes your guitar playing meaningful to you. Whatever it is that you want to do in it. If you want to play exactly like me, well, you’re going to figure that out in this lesson. If you want to play guitar playing that feels exactly like you, hopefully, we will - I’ll reveal the building blocks of how you can do that to create an authentic, artistic self on the electric guitar that’s going to be something that is going to give you a lifetime of awesome rockin’.",
            "booking_details":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
            "cost":"10.00",
            "active":1,
            "moderated":1,
            "user_id":3,
            "category_id":null,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:43:15.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2020-06-18T13:43:15.000000Z",
            "tagsList":"Music",
            "pivot":{
               "tag_id":3,
               "listing_id":9
            },
            "primary_image":[
               {
                  "id":13,
                  "type":"image",
                  "url":"https://xxxxxxx.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/music-production-simplified/primary-image-lg.jpg",
                  "is_primary":1,
                  "assetable_type":"App\\Listing",
                  "assetable_id":9,
                  "desktop":1,
                  "mobile":null,
                  "user_id":3,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:43:16.000000Z",
                  "updated_at":"2020-06-18T13:43:16.000000Z"
               },
               {
                  "id":14,
                  "type":"image",
                  "url":"https://at-home-club-1.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/music-production-simplified/primary-image-sm.jpg",
                  "is_primary":1,
                  "assetable_type":"App\\Listing",
                  "assetable_id":9,
                  "desktop":null,
                  "mobile":1,
                  "user_id":3,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":"2020-06-18T13:43:16.000000Z",
                  "updated_at":"2020-06-18T13:43:16.000000Z"
               }
            ],
            "tags":[
               {
                  "id":3,
                  "tag":"Music",
                  "weight":null,
                  "deleted_at":null,
                  "created_at":null,
                  "updated_at":null,
                  "pivot":{
                     "listing_id":9,
                     "tag_id":3
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

As you can see each object has listings array which as a number of objects in them, each of these objects has a price attribute, and I am wanting to filter out any listing objects that do not have a price of "0.00" so I can show only those that do but my attempt is not working, and I was wondering if it is because I have to descend down a few objects?

Here is my attempt,

```
filteredListings() {
            return this.tags.filter((listings) => {
                return listings.filter((l) => {
                    console.log(l.cost);
                })

            })
        }
```

Some help here would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try, I made use of `map` and inside that you can apply `filter`. Let me know if this resolves your issue:

```
givenArray.map(({listings, ...rest})=>{
    listings = listings.filter(p=>Number(p.cost)!==0);
    return {...rest, listings};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
filteredTags() {
    return this.tags.map({ listings, ...rest } => 
        ({ ...rest, listings: listings.filter(listing => listing.cost === '0.00' })
    )
}
```

Explanation:
What you are trying to do is filter the tags, while you want to filter the listings inside the tags. Therefor, you must first map over the tags and filter the listings in each tag.

Comment: This is fantastic thank you. Is possible run a check on multiple elements by && or ||?

Comment: Sure, you can just add `listing.cost === '0.00' || listing.name === 'test'` in the filter